# VBA compare 2 worksheets and extract entire work if there is a match in a column

Tags: vba, excel

I receive a monthly aging report.  I need to compare these 2 reports to find out what items appear on each of the reports.  I need a VBA to look at Column B of both sheets and if there is a match, extract those rows only.  In addition, I need a vba to find out if something has changed.  For those that are not familiar with aging report, this reports tells me how far the customer is past due in paying me.  So if customer 1, was in the Aging 0-30 (Column S) on report pulled on 20151023, then on the report pulled 20160223, this customer should be in Aging 90-120 (Column V).  I'm thinking the best way to display this information is to display matched data with no changes in the No Changes Sheet.  Then, in the sheet called Changes, I would like to display about 6 columns of information: Report Date, Dealr, Contract Number, Status, Aging History, & AR Amount. The Aging History will tell me what bucket this customer was on when the report was pulled.  This information will come from the column headings (S-X).  The AR Amount will be the amount appearing in that column.  I will try to upload a sample.

Comment: I don't know how to to upload sample data

Comment: Do you need to compare data in the same cells on both sheets or do you need to search the entire column for a match?

Comment: In other words B3 and B3 are the same on both sheets, or B3's value is found anywhere in column B on sheet 2.

Comment: Please write your code, hard to imagine your problem.

Comment: Contract, Dealr, Status, Sold Date,Aging1, Aging2, Aging3.  These are my headings.

Comment: Contract, Dealr, Status, Sold Date,Aging1, Aging2, Aging3.  These are my headings.  My data for this month's aging is 348332713\CNNAE\Not Cancelled\12/22/2015\0\$420.00\0.  Last month's data is 348332713\CNNAE\Not Cancelled\12/22/2015\$420.00\0\0.  Aging1=0-30 days, Aging2= 31-60days, etc.  I have over 430,000 rows of information each time.  I was trying to do a vlookup of Column A(34833273), but it takes too long.

Comment: Once I have found a matching contract in another worksheet, I need to know if the data in the entire row is the same.  If the data is different, and in my case, moved to another aging category (From 30 days past due to now 60 days past due), I would like to see those results in another tab.  We can that tab "Changes".  All matches that are the same can be displayed in another tab called "No Changes".

Answer (score 0):

The following gives you a way to compare the same column in two sheets.  The first way looks for a matching value anywhere in the second sheet's column, the second method only returns a match if the matching cells are on the same row in both sheets

```
Sub CompareSheets(sheet1 As Worksheet, sheet2 As Worksheet, columnNumber As Long)
  Dim ws1 As Worksheet, ws2 As Worksheet
  Dim ws1Data As Range, ws2Data As Range
  Dim col As Long
  Dim i As Integer
  Dim cell1 As Range, cell2 As Range

  Set ws1 = sheet1
  Set ws2 = sheet2
  col = columnNumber
  ws1Data = ws1.Columns(col).Cells
  ws2Data = ws2.Columns(col).Cells
```

Find a match anywhere in either column

```
  ' XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
  '   This code will find any match between the two sheets
  ' XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX

  'Checks each cell in the target column of sheet 1
  For Each cell1 In ws1Data
    'Checks each cell in the target column of sheet 2
    For Each cell2 In ws2Data
      'If the cell from sheet 1 matches any cell in sheet 2 then do stuff
      If cell1 = cell2 Then
        'Do stuff with the data here
      End If
    Next cell2
  Next cell1

  ' XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
  ' XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
```

Find a match only if the matching cells are on the same row

```
' ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
  '   This code will find a match ONLY if both entries are
  '   on the same row in their respective sheets
  ' ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

  'Checks each cell in the target column of sheet 1
  For Each cell1 In ws1Data
    'Checks each cell in the target column of sheet 2
    For Each cell2 In ws2Data
      'If the cell from sheet 1 matches any cell in sheet 2
      'AND there are on the same row in both sheets then do stuff
      If (cell1 = cell2) And (cell1.Row = cell2.Row) Then
        'Do stuff with the data here
      End If
    Next cell2
  Next cell1

  ' /////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
  ' /////////////////////////////////////////////////////////


End Sub
```

Then you can make a button or macro that calls the sub

```
Call CompareSheets(firstworksheet, secondworksheet, 2) '2 is the column number for B
```

A proper example

```
Call CompareSheets(Worksheets(1), Worksheets(2), 2)
```

As for what you want to do with the matches once they're located, that's really for another post.